The General n-Dimensional Stokes' Theorem without differential forms
I've recently become intrigued with classical tensor analysis and its relationship to differential forms. I'm particularly interested in how one would prove the general Stokes' theorem and its special cases without forms, using only classical Ricci calculus. It's been very difficult to find a proof in the literature that doesn't use forms. I understand why-the built in orientation aspect as well as the fact forms are derivations on the tangent space of a manifold make the computation very straightforward. But I think it's still worth knowing how one would prove it in the old fashioned manner-if only to see why forms are such an improvement. The only full proof in the literature I was able to find was in Synge and Schild's Tensor Calculus.I'm interested in finding others. Can anyone on here recommend other sources?

You need the exterior derivative and the fact that it commutes with pullback. Have fun doing that in the Ricci calculus framework.

@TedShifrin It turns out you CAN do it, but without the exterior derivative and its pullback it becomes incredibly tedious and complicated. You begin with decomposing a manifold into m-cells and constructing a skew symmetric extension tensor. See the aforementioned proof in Synge and Schild. It's no mystery why so few books have proven the Theorem without forms since Elle Cartan's discovery of the exterior calculus. But I think it's still useful for both historical and conceptual purposes to see how the Ricci calculus proved the result prior to the development of forms.
